NetSuite Boomi integration - System Notes
I am trying to query netsuite system notes using Boomi. However the system notes object is not available for import using the standard NetSuite connector in Boomi. We tried using ODBC, however that requires the NetSuite admin role to be given to the Boomi user. Admin role comes with 2 factor authentication which again rules out this approach. We tried connecting via suitetalk, however that has a limit of 1000 records per page and each request takes a lot of time to load. We are dealing with a few million records here. Need a a faster way to query the data. Any ideas?
